# Music with assembler - /dev/dsp in pulseaudio?

Tags: linux, assembly, open-source, alsa, pulseaudio

I want to make "music" or better just output a little "beep" with this assembler program:

play.s:

```
datei:
.ascii "/dev/dsp"

.globl play
play:
movl $5, %eax
movl $datei, %ebx
movl $1, %ecx
int $0x80
pushl %eax
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $4, %eax
movl 12(%esp), %ecx
movl 8(%esp), %edx
int $0x80
```

music.s:

```
.globl _start
#.lcomm buffer, 100
buffer:
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
.byte 0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255
_start:
pushl $buffer
pushl $100
loop:
call play
jmp loop
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $128
```

I assemblered both with:

as music.s -o music.o
as play.s -o play.o

and linked both with:

ld play.o music.o -o music

But then I registered that I do not have a "/dev/dsp"-file. **So is there any similiar to /dev/dsp in pulseaudio?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legacy `/dev/dsp` interface is not enabled by default.

To emulate it, try [padsp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/padsp) (included with PulseAudio), or [osspd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/).

Alternatively, output the sample data to stdout and pipe it into `aplay`.

Comment: mhh thats not my solution that I am looking for. I need a similiar device without emulating /dev/dsp. Emulating /dev/dsp does not work for me.

Comment: `osspd` uses a *real* device.

Comment: Ok I have a dsp device now but my code segfaults due to stack overflow. The osspd dsp device must have a write-lock or something..